# Apache - Create a new log file for every listening port

Tags: apache

I have a apache server that listens to three different random ports. I want the incoming data to be logged to three different files. Also is it possible to create a new log file every minute?

Answer (score 0):

You'd simply add the log directives to each virtual host, e.g.:

```
LogLevel info
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/first_site_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/first_site_access.log combined
..
```

Apache itself has no feature to rotate logs so you'd have to use something like logrotate and configure it accordingly.

Here's an excellent article describing every step in detail:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-apache-on-an-ubuntu-vps